# How to create a chatbot with facebook messenger like templates

Tags: bots, chatbot, messenger

I'm trying to create a chatbot for use in a chat app I've created. I basically need the chatbot to send me replies that have message templates like in facebook messenger. For example, If I type in "what's the weather like", I want my chatbot's reply to look like facebook's media template, linked here: [Media Template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/media)

Does anyone have any tutorials or links I can follow?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Usavaully work flow of chat application as follows,

1. Message providers(Facebook, twitter,slack etc..) receives messages from user
2. Message is sent to the configured endpoint(your webserver) according to the settings provided in the face book developer page [reference](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-create-your-very-own-facebook-messenger-bot-with-dialogflow-and-node-js-in-just-one-day-f5f2f5792be5)
3. In the webserver you classify the intent prepares the response according to the request and sends the responses back.

So in the 3rd point web server you give responses based on the platform you are responding to [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/ex-resp-card.html), since in your case it's your own platform you need to design your own UI based on the response format or you can use some predefined html templates.

I hope answer gave some direction to work on.